# What is Black Vinegar?

Tags: asian-cuisine

I get this truly awesome vinegar, BLack Vinegar, at some Asian grocery stores around Los Angeles. I have been saying its similar to Bragg liquid Aminos.

I have no idea what it's made out of,  does anyone know for a fact what it is?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_vinegar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinegar#East_Asian_black ?

Comment: To the close voters: Please note that there is no "general reference" close reason across the network, ---so this question is *on topic*.--- On the other hand, we have a meta proposal to not accept these questions. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason for the network-wide discussion and http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1023/41 for ours. I will keep back with the hammer vote in this disputed case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Black Vinegar is basically what it's called, and has a smoky and mellow flavor. It is made from rice, sometimes from glutinous rice and is sometimes used as a full-flavored but much cheaper balsamic vinegar. 
Hope this helps! :)